# Scheduler program in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I am working on a client server project. Client is built in WPF using mvvm pattern and service is built using WCF. I have to perform some action on a specific event which I am able to do by calling some service functions. I will have to do call the same function on a regular basis at a specific time as configured in database. Can somebody suggest a better approach to achieve this. I am thinking of creating a windows service specifically to do such things. Is that a good choice ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I understood, you have to call the web service from the WPF app, haven't you? if that is the case, I see no reason why would one create a web service in this case... Why don't you create a simple Timer in your app?

Comment: We are using WCF services to perform all the server side operations. Client cannot do all these. Timer option work if we have the app open all the time. I want the task to be performed on a regular interval at a specific time say every midnight at 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a console app that calls the service, and add a scheduled task in Windows to run the console app at a specified interval.  It is a lot easier and cleaner than creating a service for such a simple application.

Comment: Thanks for the quickest reply. This seems to be a good approach. I will try something in this line.My design should be capable of handling few more such requirements going forward and should not just end with this.This should be a base for all going forward.

Comment: You may get different results, but in my experience, just using the built in stuff on whatever OS you are using to call programs at specified intervals is way easier than trying to invent your own system or using scheduling libs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use an already created (and properly tested) scheduling system or library instead of developing your own.  For a Java project I worked on, I used the Quartz library, which handled the job quite nicely and it integrated easily into said project. It has a .NET port [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quartznet/), never used it but I suppose it works similarly.

Comment: Thanks for posting about the library and approach. Appreciate it.I will explore more by going through it.